# How to reduce socket connection time in java?

Tags: java, sockets, time, connection

I have client/server program that uses sockets.
On server side I have

```
ServerSocket s=new ServerSocket(8888);
s.setSoTimeout(10000);
Socket incoming=s.accept(); 
ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
ObjectInputStream ios = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
s.close();
oos.close();
ios.close();
incoming.close();
```

On client side I have

```
Socket s=new Socket("172.17.20.47", 8888);      
ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
ObjectInputStream ios = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
s.close();
oos.close();
ios.close();
```

When I measured the time like:

```
long start= System.CurrentTimeMillis();    
Socket incoming=s.accept();
long end= System.CurrentTimeMillis();
System.out.println(end-start);
```

I showed that `Socket incoming=s.accept();` takes ~450ms. 
How can I reduce this time? Because all the rest part of code takes up to ~15ms.

ping between computers is <1ms

Comment: `accept()` is blocked until a request comes. So your measurement of time is not accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer on this would be to read Eng.Fouad's comment.
The accept function in the ServerSocket class waits until a incoming request comes.
If you have waited 5 hours before you started your client code the accept function will have been taking 18000000ms!! You cant make that function faster, it is already as fast as it could be.
*(joke: you can reduce the time of the accept function by start the client faster..) :)*
Hope you understand why the accept function take so much time(really it' not).

Comment: But, the thing is that I'm starting client at the same time as server and they doing the same amount of computation before connection

Comment: It's irrelevant how long accept() took. All you're measuring is the real meaning of 'at the same time'. What you should be measuring is the time to connect in the client.